# Updating a List<Class>

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a list of a class, how do I find edit the class at a particular list location.

I am trying to update a `List<Class>`, but I have no idea how to pass the values back to the class.
i.e. I do not know how to call the list at location 2 changed the class values 1,2,3,4,5 to 6,7,8,9,0

the class is a form and the method I want to use will essentially be:

```
public FormStudent(int a, string b, int c, double d, char f)
{
    textBoxID.Text = a.ToString();
    textBoxName.Text = b;
    textBoxCredits.Text = c.ToString();
    textBoxTuition.Text = d.ToString();
    if (f == 'R')
        radioButtonResident.Checked = true;
    else
        adioButtonNonResident.Checked = true;
}
```

My list is:

```
  private List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
```

oh! and to make it even more difficult I am getting the list value from a listView via

```
private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student stu = new Student();

    ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems;
    int count = selectedItems.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {                   
        // I NEED THE UPDATE HERE TO CALL \/
        FormStudent stuInfoForm = new FormStudent(stu.Id, stu.Name, stu.Credits, stu.Tuition, stu.Residency);

        studentList.RemoveAt(i);
        stuInfoForm.Owner = this;
        stuInfoForm.ShowDialog();
    }
    refreshList();
}
```

Comment: Just to clariy, you problem is, how to update your `Student stu` object, from the selectedItems of ListView?  Is this correct?

Comment: I am trying basicly to pass the values from the already set Student stu at location studentlist at location listview1 to the form in which it was originally created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only use the Id member of student to pass but you can pass it all.

Basically in your main form you had:

```
 private List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

 private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems;
        if (selectedItems != null && selectedItems.Count > 0) {
            ListViewItem item = selectedItems[0];
            Form2 form = new Form2(item.Text);
            form.Owner = this;
            form.ShowDialog();

            // Now get the values from the form.
            Student updateStudent = studentList.Find(o => o.Id == form.Student.Id);
            if (updateStudent != null) {
                updateStudent.Id = form.Student.Id;
                // Update the rest of the members.
            }

            // Re-populate your list using the updated student list.
        }
    }
```

Now in your second form student form:

```
    private Student _student = new Student();

    public Form2(string id) {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = id;
    }

    public Student Student {
        get {
            return _student;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        _student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

just index it:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
...
list.Add(5);

list[2] = 7;
```

Comment: erm, that works with a basic list, but this is a list<class> think of it as a list<array>.

Comment: It will still work, a list<class> or list<int> or list<list<int>> all basically the same, because its a list<T> which is generics. So as Christo stated above you can use the index to retrieve at specific position.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a databind? It is hard to actually understand what you are doing. It seems like you are removing students at the same time as you are creating them, seems weird.

Comment: I am trying to take the values from the studentlist for students pass them to a form that will allow me to edit them and resubmit them. The studentlist will be identified by listview selected item. I just dont know how to go about taking that information and passing the proper values.